# Type parameter of minBy[B](f: ((A, B)) ⇒ B)(implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): (A, B)

Tags: scala, type-parameter

The trait `Map[A,+B]` has a method

```
def minBy [B] (f: ((A, B)) ⇒ B)(implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): (A, B)
```

I expected the `B` of the trait to be the same as the one in the method, but then I can't still make sense of this:

```
val m2 = Map('a -> "1", 'b ->"2" ,'c ->"3")
m2.minBy((t:(Symbol,String))=>Integer.parseInt(t._2))
```

Here, `B` of `Map[A,+B]` is `String`, but `B` of `minBy` is `Int` - or err I?

So I expected the type of the method to be rather

```
def minBy [C] (f: ((A, B)) ⇒ C)(implicit cmp: Ordering[C]): (A, B)
```

But thats not what the source says.

If both are distinct, where should I have known?
If they are not - can you spot, and point out, my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You analysis is correct, it should be renamed as C, or something else. The problem is that scaladoc is simply replacing the A in the definition in TraversableLike with a Tuple (A, B) because it's a map. This is the definition from TraversableLike:

```
def minBy [B] (f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): A
```

because it's a map, scaladoc replaces the (A) with a tuple (A, B).

```
def minBy [B] (f: (A, B) ⇒ B)(implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): (A, B)
```

which as you observe, isn't actually the correct signature.

This is a known issue, [scaladoc does not disambiguate between same-named type parameters](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3834). Vote it up or submit a patch!

Comment: Ah, okay, I was wrong about that source remark. The minBy method is declared in GenTraversableOnce, then defined in TraversableOnce - and both dont know about B. So it is really a scaladoc issue. Thank you both.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like the software that builds the documentation has simply failed to rename the `B` variable from the trait's definition of `minBy`, thus causing a name clash.  Your analysis seems correct.

To use the terminology from lambda calculus, I'd say that the software failed to [alpha-convert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_conversion#.CE.B1-conversion).