# What are the rules for when trait/class type parameters take precedence vs method type parameters

Tags: scala, type-parameter

I've been using scala for a while now and I thought I was really starting to understand everything (well, most things...), but I found myself confused by a number of the method definitions in the Map class. I know how foldLeft, etc work, but what I'm confused about is the type parameters used in the Map functions. Let's use foldLeft as an example:

```
foldLeft [B] (z: B)(op: (B, (A, B)) ⇒ B) : B
```

The definition for the Map trait itself takes two type parameters 'A' and 'B' (e.g. Map[A,+B]). From what I can tell, when you define a type parameter for a method using the same name as one of the type parameters for the class/trait, it overrides the class/trait value. Take this definition of Foo as an example:

```
class Foo[A : Manifest, B : Manifest] {
  def isAString() = manifest[A] == manifest[String]
  def isAInt() = manifest[A] == manifest[Int]
  def isBString() = manifest[B] == manifest[String]
  def isBInt() = manifest[B] == manifest[Int]
  def nowIsBString[B : Manifest] = manifest[B] == manifest[String]
}

scala> val f = new Foo[String,Int]
f: Foo[String,Int] = Foo@7bacb41

scala> f.isAString
res290: Boolean = true

scala> f.isAInt
res291: Boolean = false

scala> f.isBString
res292: Boolean = false

scala> f.isBInt
res293: Boolean = true

scala> f.nowIsBString[String]
res294: Boolean = true

scala> f.nowIsBString[Int]
res295: Boolean = false
```

So in the foldLeft definition, 'B' comes from the method definition and 'A' comes from the trait definition. For example:

```
val xm = Map("test" -> 1, "test2" -> 2)

scala> val foldFn = (z: Int, kv: (String, Int)) => z + kv._2 
foldFn: (Int, (String, Int)) => Int = <function2>

scala> m.foldLeft(0)(foldFn)
res298: Int = 3
```

This is as expected as 'B' for the function matches 'B' for the trait, but what if I change the 'B' type for the function to String instead of Int:

```
scala> val foldFn = (z: String, kv: (String, String)) => z + kv._2 
foldFn: (String, (String, String)) => java.lang.String = <function2>

scala> m.foldLeft("")(foldFn)
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, (String, String)) => java.lang.String
 required: (java.lang.String, (java.lang.String, Int)) => java.lang.String
              m.foldLeft("")(foldFn)
```

So let's change the kv parameter to (String, Int):

```
scala> val foldFn = (z: String, kv: (String, Int)) => z + kv._2 
foldFn: (String, (String, Int)) => java.lang.String = <function2>

scala> m.foldLeft("")(foldFn)
res299: java.lang.String = 12
```

Unlike my Foo example, in this case the Map's 'B' value is taking precedence over the functions definition, but only for the kv parameter. What I would have expected is to see a foldLeft defined as follows:

```
foldLeft[C] (z: C)(op: (C, (A, B)) => C): C
```

That would be more clear to me, but it is not defined this way. So does anyone know the rules for when a methods parameter will override a trait/class parameter and when it will not?

Comment: For some reason I seem to only find the answer to my question after I post :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397684/type-parameter-of-minbybf-a-b-bimplicit-cmp-orderingb-a-b  However, I would still like to know if there are any rules for figuring out when this has occured

Comment: `foldLeft` is defined on `TraversableOnce`. It's `A` parameter is that of `TraversableOnce`, not that of `Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala is the same as Java in this respect, and the following from the "Names" chapter of [the Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/names.html) applies:

> A declaration *d* of a type named *n* shadows the declarations of any
>   other types named *n* that are in scope at the point where *d* occurs
>   throughout the scope of *d*.

So the type parameter for a method will always shadow a class or trait type parameter with the same name. Your `Foo` example demonstrates this fact.

The apparent counterexample you're seeing in the case of `Map`'s `foldLeft` is just [an unpleasant artifact](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3834) of the current version of Scaladoc, as is [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398311/334519) in the answers to the question you've linked. `foldLeft` isn't defined in the `Map` trait, but in [`TraversableOnce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html), where there isn't a trait type parameter named `B` at all.

In general shadowing the type parameter of a trait or class in a method is a really bad idea, of course.