# Scala Type Mismatch Error on Map

Tags: scala, type-erasure

What am I missing here?
This is the error I am getting...

> error: type mismatch; found   : List[Double](in method
>    calculateHaarWaveletI)]
>
> required: List[scala.Double]
>
> Console.println(list2Tuples(ls.take(n)))

Here is my code..

```
    object HaarWavelet {

  def calculateHaarWavelet(ls: List[Double]): List[Double] = {
    if (ls.length % 2 != 0) throw new RuntimeException("Need even number of elements to calculate HaarWavelet")
    calculateHaarWaveletI(ls, ls.length)
    def calculateHaarWaveletI[Double](ls: List[Double], n: Int): List[Double] = {
      Console.println(list2Tuples(ls.take(n)))
      null
    }
    null
  }

  def processTuple(x: (Double, Double)): (Double, Double) = {
    val f = (x._1 + x._2) / 2
    (f, x._1 - f)
  }

  def list2Tuples(ls: List[Double]): List[(Double, Double)] = {
    if (ls.isEmpty) return List()
    (ls.head, ls.tail) match {
      case (_, Nil) => List()
      case (x, y) => List((x, y.head)) ::: list2Tuples(y.tail)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Console.println("Starting....")
    Console.println(calculateHaarWavelet(List(8.0, 4.0)))
    Console.println("Done....")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your type parameter `Double` in the definition of `calculateHaarWaveletI` is shadowing `scala.Double`. You can just remove the type parameter altogether and the code should work as expected. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9958940/334519) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I Initially added a type param to all the methods and then later deleted them, this one somehow got away :)